# Django in Google Cloud App Engine: ImportError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my Django 1.10 app in Google Cloud App Engine flexible environment but i'am having the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named src
```

I'm following the official tutorial, located in: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

The error is generated when I run the following command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

after a while, the console showme this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
[1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named src.settings
[9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

This is my app.yaml config:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT core.wsgi

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: nazkter-zed:us-central1:nazkter-zed

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
# [END runtime]
```

and this is my proyect structure:

```
- core/
-- app.yaml
-- requeriments.txt
-- manage.py
-- core/
--- __init__.py
--- settings.py
--- wsgi.py
--- urls.py
-- app1/
--- __init__.py
--- admin.py
--- apps.py
--- models.py
--- views.py
--- urls.py
```

I'm been arround this error all day and I want to know what is generating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking for the settings.py file in the src directory, according to how you set up the Django app. Try moving the settings.py file to your src dir and run the command again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you make me note that the file wsgy.py was searching for "src/setting.py", but my setting file is located in "core/setting.py". I just changed that line and everything runs correctly.

Comment: @Nazkter what did you change specifically?

Comment: @JudeMaranga inside the file "wsgi.py" inside your project, there is a path to the settings file, I changed that path

Comment: @Nazkter yeah like what's the exact value you changed it to?